# as3 issue with navigateToURL post methods

Tags: actionscript-3, http-post

I have a page containing a flash object. On a particular action the page needs to redirect to some other page and also send some data (variables). I am using the urlvariables and navigateToURL in conjunction to do this. The page redirects and the data (variables) is sent.

But the issue is that the data(variables) are being sent in the query string (I mean like this "http://dummy.php/?first_name=xyz"). I am using the post method to send the data (variables). I cannot send the data (variables) like a query string.

How to solve this issue?

PS: I have written all the code here below...

```
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://dummy.php");
var vars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
vars.first_name = 'xyz';
request.data = vars;
request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
navigateToURL(request, "_blank");
```

Comment: This code seems correct. What is the issue with it?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi you see the data is being sent as query string (will be attached to the end of the php page url like this "/?first_name=xyz"). I don't want this to happen... You understand what i mean.

Comment: @Sravan0313 no, it's not happening to me. The URL is clean, and the vars are passed via POST as expected.

Comment: @protozoo you mean the variables are not posted as query strings but, sent inside the body??? because it doesn't happen to me the variables are always sent through query string for me...

Comment: @Sravan0313 yes, in my test the URL doesn't show any variables, and I can see in Firebug that they are being passed via POST.

Answer (score 2):

I just made this simple test sending a POST request to the Twitter's search API (it seems to accept both GET and POST requests). As you can see in the attached screenshot, the browser's URL field is not showing any vars, and Httpfox (you can do the same thing with Firebug, Chrome's developer tools, etc...) shows variables being passed by POST as expected. The example code you posted is the real one that is causing you trouble? Here's what I used:

```
    // Create the POST request
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://search.twitter.com/search.json");
request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

// Create the variables object
var vars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
vars.q = 'love';
vars.rpp = '5';
vars.include_entities = 'true';

// Attach variables to request object
request.data = vars;

// Open new window using the POST request
navigateToURL(request, "_blank");
```

[image: Httpfox screenshot showing POST vars being passed as expected]

Answer (score 1):

Are you adhereing to the various rules and limitations imposed?

> When sending a POST request, the values of the contentType and data properties must correspond properly. The value of the contentType property instructs servers on how to interpret the value of the data property.
>
> If the value of the data property is a URLVariables object, the value of contentType must be application/x-www-form-urlencoded.
>   If the value of the data property is any other type, the value of contentType should indicate the type of the POST data that will be sent (which is the binary or string data contained in the value of the data property).
>   For FileReference.upload(), the Content-Type of the request is set automatically to multipart/form-data, and the value of the contentType property is ignored.
>
> In Flash Player 10 and later, if you use a multipart Content-Type (for example "multipart/form-data") that contains an upload (indicated by a "filename" parameter in a "content-disposition" header within the POST body), the POST operation is subject to the security rules applied to uploads:
>   The POST operation must be performed in response to a user-initiated action, such as a mouse click or key press.
>   If the POST operation is cross-domain (the POST target is not on the same server as the SWF file that is sending the POST request), the target server must provide a URL policy file that permits cross-domain access.
>   Also, for any multipart Content-Type, the syntax must be valid (according to the RFC2046 standards). If the syntax appears to be invalid, the POST operation is subject to the security rules applied to uploads.

Maybe something is causing it default back to a GET-request.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurred for me when I was doing the following:

```
var vars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
vars.q = 'http://example.com/var1=7&var2=9';
```

The get style vars are apparently not automatically URL encoded and cause Flash to revert from the set POST method to the GET method. I used URL encoding and the problem when away.

```
vars.q = encodeURIComponent('http://example.com/var1=7&var2=9');
```